# Browser freezed if zoomed on empty place of the chart area

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

TYPE Highstock while Multiple series with empty data freezed on zooming the whitespace at the chart unable to close after chart zoomed.

```
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
  chart: {
    zoomType: 'x',
  },

  tooltip: {
    enabled: true,
    split: false,
    shared: true,
  },
  
  rangeSelector: {
    enabled: false,
  },

  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    ordinal: false,
  },

  series: [{
    name: 'Chart 1',
    type: 'line',
    color: 'red',
    dataGrouping: {
      approximation: 'high',
    },
    step: 'left',
    data: data1,
  }, {
    name: 'Chart 2',
    type: 'line',
    color: 'blue',
    dataGrouping: {
      approximation: 'high',
    },
    step: 'left',
    data: data2,
  }]

});
```

chack while setting up The default `minRange` for the x axis is five times smallest interval between any of the data points.

Comment: when i clicked the space between chart also getting this error

Comment: Hi @Narasimhan R, Could you reproduce the problem in some online code editor? Here: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zmp0a5xr/ everything works as expected.